# IE returning error in javascript function

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

this function works in all browser:-

```
 $scope.changeTime = function(date,format='D MMMM, YYYY'){
       var time= moment(date, 'YYYY-MM-DD').format(format);

       return time;
    }
```

but Internet explorer throws this error-

***"Expected ')'"**

i suspect internet explorer doesn't take default param value in javascript function.

how can make it work in Internet explorer.

Comment: _Which_ IE? Also, yes, it most likely doesn't have ES6 support.

Comment: It doesn't support default values for function parameters. Either transpile your ES6 to a version of JS IE understands or stop using default parameters.

Comment: Yeah, just double checked [IE is listed as having "no support"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters)

Comment: Pff, I might have expected IE 11 to _maybe_ have that but definitely not IE10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default parameter values are not yet supported in all browsers. Instead use something like this:

```
$scope.changeTime = function(date, theFormat) {
    var format = theFormat || 'YYYY-MD-DD';
    var time = moment(date, 'YYYY-MM-DD').format(format);

    return time;
}
```